# WebSocket route on FastAPI doesn't work on deta space deployment only on localhost

Tags: python, websocket, deployment, localhost, fastapi

I've got a problem with websockets after I deploy my fast api project on
Deta Space my test websocket route not working. However on my localhost this route is working well, so sorry for my bad english

Here we go, this is my test websocket route

```
app = FastAPI(
    title='websocket test',
    description="The description",
    version='062023.1'
)
allow_all = ['*']
app.add_middleware(
   CORSMiddleware,
   allow_origins=allow_all,
   allow_credentials=True,
   allow_methods=allow_all,
   allow_headers=allow_all
)

@app.websocket('/ws')
async def websocket_echo(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    try: 
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            await websocket.send_text(f'You send: {data}')
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print('user disconnected')
```

So simple code, got it from fast api websocket tutorial a bit different maybe
Also I've got Vue-component text-field that send message to this route after click send button

```
// CREATE CONNECTION
let socket = new WebSocket(`wss://fastapitouch-1-l4518065.deta.app/ws`)

// SEND MESSAGE
socket.send(this.message)

// ON MESSAGE FROM SERVER LOG IT
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(`Message from server: ${event.data}`)
}
```

After click on, I've got an error mesage in my deta space builder logs that this route wasn't found -
#404 route not found (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I8aY.png)

In my console I've got this message -
WebSocket connection to 'wss://fastapitouch-1-l4518065.deta.app/webs' failed (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdo7W.png)

I've tried to find info about it but no one wasn't deploying stuff like that and note it or make video about

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Deta Space [does not support websockets](https://deta.space/docs/en/build/reference/runtime/#important-notes-for-micros) (see point 10).

Answer (score 0):

just saw this - here's some useful info:

1. to make routes public you need to define it in the Spacefile

```yaml
micros:
  - name: your-name
    public_routes:
      - "/test/*"
...
```

2. from the deta.space documentation:
   https://deta.space/docs/en/build/reference/runtime/

```
Important Notes for Micros
...
10. Websockets and long-running processes do not work on Micros. (examples: socket.io or Discord bots won’t work).
```